# Hadoop "only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation."

Tags: hadoop

today when I run  `hadoop fs -put test.txt /usr/qiuyang`  in the `Namenode` machine,if the `test.txt` file is empty,there are not any error.But if the file isn't empty,it will create the error as below:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File
 /usr/qiuyang/test.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

i check the operating condition of datanode by using `jps`，it manifests the node is runing well. At the same time,I check the firewall in `Namenode` and `Datanode`,they have been closed.
so why I still encountered this problem?
thank your answer.

Comment: ok，i know the reason.Because i close the port 50010

Comment: Please post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

open port 50010 (as you stated in your comment)

Comment: ok,thank you,this is my first time using it